# WARNING: itunes store operation failed error (null)

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Error when validating the app to itunesconnect, Itunesconnect status showing Invalid Binary.

See the Image below for more detail

[image: iTunes Store operation failed.]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the problem:

> Missing 64-bit support - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps
>   submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built
>   with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need
>   to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we
>   recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard
>   architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit
>   code.
>   [image]
>   [image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you tell me how convert my app from 32 bit to 64 bit.

Comment: Edited the original one,Check those snapshots.

Comment: It is one of the reason for that warning,if u are still getting same warning then i think its because of any other problem.

Comment: I get the same error (null) since this is the only hit on a google search, could it be some temporary error at apple?

Comment: No i think..........its because of several reasons one of them was i told u.....let me do more R&D about this i ll get back to u once i found another reason.

Comment: Tried to upload again today, Uploaded successfully.